# Zoom in/out in image, keep position under cursor at same place

Tags: javascript

I have been struggling for a while with a Angular application that has one component with a map. To be able to rule out any other problems I have done a rewrite in pure javascript to test the functionality but I can't figure out how to solve this.

What I want to do is the same kind of functionality as in for example Google Maps, If you have the cursor over a specific city and zoom in with the mouse scroll then the map zooms in but keeps the city at the same place under the cursor.

I have this code and it's the function "**zoomImage**" that give me problems..
https://codepen.io/m-rten-sw-rd/pen/BMZvZX

Anyone that could guide me right on this?

```
function zoomImage(scale, mousePosInCointainer, mousePosInImage) {
  var imgElement = document.getElementById("img");
  imgElement.width = imgElement.width * scale;
  imgElement.height = imgElement.height * scale;

  /* TODO: Determine how I'm going to center the image over cursor */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following is what you need to be doing.

1. Determine transform origin (should be center) of the image.
2. Determine difference between mouse cursor and that point.
3. Scale that difference by your scale factor.
4. Translate the image by that difference.

Comment: the transform origin is much more likely to be the top-left of the image

Comment: I can't figure out how to do this. I have tried for hours now to get my head around this but I fail..